# How to pass a .class-type parameter into a method

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

```
PersonenGenerator{
Set<Person> personSet = new HashSet<>();

public void printPersonTypeSet(Class clazz){ //pass a class that inherits from the class Person as a parameter
    for(Person instance : personSet){    
        if (instance instanceof clazz) System.out.println(instance);
    } // check if instance of Class Person are stored in personSet. If so, print said instance
}


public class Student extends Person{
...
}
public class Employee extends Person{
...
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PersonenGenerator pg = new PersonenGenerator();
        pg.Student s1 = new Student(...);
        pg.personSet.add(s1);
        pg.Employee e1 = new Employee(...);
        pg.personSet.add(e1);


        printPersonTypeSet(Employee) //pass Employee as parameter SOMEHOW
    }
}
```

EXPECTED BEHAVIOUR (Output):

> Employee{value1, value2, value3}

My Compiler does not like the if-statement for some reason. Specifically where i call `clazz`.

ACTUAL BEHAVIOR (Compiler Error) :

> Unknown Class:'clazz'

My problem is that I intend to use `clazz` as a variable for instances of `Person`, while `Person` is the superclass for various subclasses.

How do I keep the intended functionality and satisfy my compiler?
First time doing this.

EDIT: I feel like I've been misunderstood. I want to pass a class as the parameter under which the condition is checked. I commented the code to clarify this.

If passing the parameter as type `Class` is bullshit for this, just say so. It was an idea, because I don't know how to pass a class as parameter.

Comment: your class is Class not clazz. That's why the error is occurring.

Comment: can you write an answer? I don't think I understand what you are reffering to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `clazz.isAssignableFrom(instance.getClass())`. This returns `true` if `instance` has type `clazz` or is a subtype of type `clazz`.

Edit: here's a more complete example. You have a `Person` class and some subclasses:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    Person(String n) { name = n; }
    public String toString() { return name; }
}

class GoodPerson extends Person {
    GoodPerson(String n) {
        super(n);
    }
}

class BadPerson extends Person {
    BadPerson(String n) {
        super(n);
    }
}
```

Then you use your code with my suggested edit:

```
public void printPersonTypeSet(Class<?> clazz) {
    for (Person instance : personSet)
        if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(instance.getClass()))
            System.out.println(instance);
}
```

If `personSet` is initialized as:

```
Set<Person> personSet = new HashSet<Person>();
personSet.add(new GoodPerson("Good1"));
personSet.add(new GoodPerson("Good2"));
personSet.add(new BadPerson("Bad1"));
```

then you can find the instances of `GoodPerson` by using `printPersonTypeSet(GoodPerson.class)`. (Note this will also find subclasses of `GoodPerson`.)

Comment: can you correct my code? I don't think I understand what you are saying

Comment: Replace `instance instanceof clazz` in your code with `clazz.isAssignableFrom(instance.getClass())`.

Comment: I clarified with comments where I want to go with this. I feel like my question was not well understood

Comment: I understood your question (i.e., what you said in your edit) before your edit. I still think this is what you want. Suppose `JavaProgrammer` is a subclass of `Person`, and you call `printPersonTypeSet(JavaProgrammer.class)`. Using your existing code with my modification, you will print out all JavaProgrammers and skip other kinds of Person objects.

Comment: @BlkPengu I edited my answer with more details. If this is still not what you wanted, please ask a new question with more details about why my solution doesn't satisfy your needs.

Comment: I heavily edited the question with some context code. I understand your answer like I'm supposed to pass an instance of the class I want to use as comparator for the `personList` content instances. Is this correct? Because (now referencing the 2nd edit) I want to pass something to the extent of `printPersonTypeSet(Employee)`, while `Employee` is a class itself that inherits from Person.

Comment: Your new code example adds `s1` to the `personSet` twice, instead of `e1`. Then, you should call `pg.printPersonTypeSet(Employee.class)`. Please make these changes and see if the output is what you wanted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169373/discussion-between-blkpengu-and-pkpnd).

Comment: Can you help me Improve my question? I want my 4 points back :)

Comment: I actually thought your question was good and just upvoted to negate the downvotes

Answer (score 1):

In your example `clazz` is an instance of `Class`, and that's probably not what you want to give as parameter in your method. So you're asking your compiler if `instance` is an instance of `clazz`, which it can't be as `clazz` is not a class but an instance.

Comment: I clarified with comments where I want to go with this. I feel like my question was not well understood

Comment: Can you help me improve my question?  It got downvoted pretty bad and I got a question ban as a result. I want my points back :)

Answer (score 1):

The best would be using the `isInstance(Class)` method. According to the Java documentation This method is the dynamic equivalent of the Java language instanceof operator.

```
public void printPersonTypeSet(Class clazz){
    Set<Person> personSet = ImmutableSet.of(new Person());
    for(Person instance : personSet){
        if (clazz.isInstance(instance.getClass())) System.out.println(instance);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Scratch().printPersonTypeSet(Person.class);
}
```

**From Java doc:**

> Determines if the specified {@code Object} is assignment-compatible
>   with the object represented by this {@code Class}.  This method is
>   the dynamic equivalent of the Java language {@code instanceof}
>   operator. The method returns {@code true} if the specified
>   {@code Object} argument is non-null and can be cast to the
>   reference type represented by this {@code Class} object without
>   raising a {@code ClassCastException.} It returns {@code false}
>   otherwise.

**Method Signature**

`public native boolean isInstance(Object obj)`

Comment: I clarified with comments where I want to go with this. I feel like my question was not well understood

Comment: Is there any particular reason why this was a bad question? I want my points back :)

Comment: I don't think it's a bad question. I will upvote for you :)